# descriptive statistics in table r for multiple variables

Tags: r, statistics

I am totally new with R and I'll appreciate the time anyone bothers to take with helping me with these probably simple tasks. I'm just at a loss with all the resources available and am not sure where to start.

My data looks something like this:

```
    subject sex age nR  medL    medR        meanL       meanR   pL  ageBin
1   0146si  1   67  26  1   1   1.882353    1.5294118   0.5517241   1
2   0162le  1   72  5   2   1   2           1.25        0.6153846   1
3   0323er  1   54  30  2.5 3   2.416667    2.5         0.4915254   0
4   0811ne  0   41  21  2   2   2           1.75        0.5333333   0
5   0825en  1   44  31  2   2   2.588235    1.8235294   0.5866667   0
```

Though the actual data has many, many more subjects in variables.

This first thing I need to do is compare the 'ageBin' values. 0 = under age 60, 1 = over age 60. I want to compare stats between these two groups. So I guess the first thing I need is the ability to recognize the different ageBin values and make those the two rows.

Then I need to do things like calculate the frequency of the values in the two groups (ie. how many instances of 1 and 0), the mean of the 'age' variable, the median of the age variable, number of males (ie. sex = 1), the mean of meanL, etc. Simple things like that. I just want them to be all in one table.

So an example of a potential table might be

```
            n   nMale   mAge
ageBin 0    14      x     x
ageBin 1    14      x     x
```

I could easily do this stuff in SPSS or even Excel...I just really want to get started with R. So any resource or advice someone could offer to point me in the right direction would be so, so helpful. Sorry if this sounds unclear...I can try to clarify if necessary.

Thanks in advance, anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `plyr()` package to split up the data structure and then apply a function to combine all the results back together.

```
install.packages("plyr") # install package from CRAN
library(plyr) # load the package into R

dd <- list(subject=c("0146si", "0162le", "1323er", "0811ne", "0825en"),
       sex = c(1,1,1,0,1),
       age = c(67,72,54,41,44),
       nR = c(26,5,30,21,31),
       medL = c(1,2,2.5,2,2),
       medR = c(1,1,3,2,2),
       meanL = c(1.882352,2,2.416667,2,2.588235),
       meanR = c(1.5294118,1.25,2.5,1.75,1.8235294),
       pL = c(0.5517241,0.6153846,0.4915254,0.5333333,0.5866667),
       ageBin = c(1,1,0,0,0))

dd <- data.frame(dd) # convert to data.frame
```

Using the `ddply` function, you can do things like calculate the frequency of the values in the two groups

```
ddply(dd, .(ageBin), summarise, nMale = sum(sex), mAge = mean(age))

ageBin nMale     mAge
0      2         46.33333
1      2         69.50000
```

The following is a very useful resource by [Sean Anderson](http://seananderson.ca/courses/12-plyr/plyr_2012.pdf) for getting up to speed with the plyr package.
A more comprehensive extremely resource by Hadley Wickham the package author can be found [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper)

Comment: This seems helpful. My actual data is HUGE though, so manually writing it all in a list like you did isn't realistic...is there a way around that with ddply?

Comment: I did it this way just for simulation purposes on my computer. Ideally you'll read your data into r using `read.table` or `read.csv` function. `ddply` is a function solely for splitting and grouping your dataframe in the format desired.
In your case you need to group other variables along the `ageBin` variable. Briefly the format for ddply is
`ddply(dataset, variables to group by, function to apply for grouping)`. Check the links provided in my post, they provide all you need to know about ddply succinctly.

Comment: @Socratease. Hi, please kindly show appreciation by upvoting. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try the `by` function:

if your data frame is named `df`:

```
by(data=df, INDICES=df$ageBin, FUN=summary)
```